# PayPal Helper need some help

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, paypal

I am trying to use this http://paypalhelper.codeplex.com in ASP.NET MVC 3.0 application.

so the steps i done:

1) Register PayPal helper with my test values in Global.asax

```
PayPal.Profile.Initialize("namehere", "passwordhere", "signaturehere", "sandbox");
```

2) Than on razor view i declared the buy now button:

```
@{
var paypalButton = PayPal.ButtonManager.BuyNowButton.Create("sellerhere", "itemname", "10.00");
HtmlString paypalButtonHtml = new HtmlString(paypalButton.WebSiteCode);
}

@paypalButtonHtml
```

so in result i've got that html:

```
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="SECRET_VALUE_HERE"/>
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>
```

than after i click that button the page getting posted to my application, but i was expected that it would be redirected to the `paypal` website to proceed payment.

Am i missed something?

What else i should do to redirect user to `paypal paynow` page?

Answer (score 1):

Did you place `@paypalButtonHtml` outside of your own `<form>` element?

I use the paypal helper in production and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller code, go to the post method and put return new RedirectResult(dredirectUrl); at the end instead of return View()